# Arabic text is revering lines in reportlab

Tags: python, python-3.x, arabic, reportlab, bidi

In reportLab, I need to display an arabic paragraph. I am using arabic-resharper and bidi-algorithm. The problem appears in the algorithm that reverses lines.

My code is:

```
def format_arabic_paragraph(arabic_text: str, paragraph_style: ParagraphStyle):
        reshaped_text = arabic_reshaper.reshape(arabic_text)
        bidirectional_text = algorithm.get_display(reshaped_text)
        formatted_paragraph = Paragraph(bidirectional_text, paragraph_style)
        return formatted_paragraph

arabic_text='وحدة1 وحدة2'
```

Here's the output:
وحدة2
وحدة1

Here's what I expected:
وحدة1
وحدة2

Comment: I have tried another library called pyfribidi. It seems that the problem with ReportLab staring Arabic paragraph from  buttom.

Comment: bidi-algorithm converts the string from logical ordering to visual ordering, and in the process reverse the order of words within the string. First word in arabic_text is `وحدة1` but first word after reorderng the string using bidi_algorithm is `وحدة2`. You would need to reverse the order of the words before return.

Comment: It does not reverse the word order. It reverses the lines by rendering the lines from the bottom of the paragraph. Hence, I think the problem is with the report lab and how it renders RTL text. Now, I'm working on a text wrapper to fix this problem. However, I would like to see if there is a stable solution.

Comment: Converting it from logical to visual reverses the string, but that in itself automatically changes the word order. In Logical order first character in data should be the right most character in display. First word in data is word rendered right most on first line. Converting the string to visual order changes string so left most word is first word in string (but word is backwards). It's easier to observe when looking at the codepoints.

Comment: `arabic_text` is `U+0648 (و) U+062D (ح) U+062F (د) U+0629 (ة) U+0031 (1) U+0020( ) U+0648 (و) U+062D (ح) U+062F (د) U+0629 (ة) U+0032 (2)`. So first sub-string is `U+0648 (و) U+062D (ح) U+062F (د) U+0629 (ة) U+0031 (1)` while second is `U+0648 (و) U+062D (ح) U+062F (د) U+0629 (ة) U+0032 (2)`. For `bidirectional_text` you have `U+0032 (2) U+FE93 (ﺓ) U+FEAA (ﺪ) U+FEA3 (ﺣ) U+FEED (ﻭ) U+0020 ( ) U+0031 (1) U+FE93 (ﺓ) U+FEAA (ﺪ) U+FEA3 (ﺣ) U+FEED (ﻭ)`. So first sub-string is `U+0032 (2) U+FE93 (ﺓ) U+FEAA (ﺪ) U+FEA3 (ﺣ) U+FEED (ﻭ)` and 2nd: `U+0031 (1) U+FE93 (ﺓ) U+FEAA (ﺪ) U+FEA3 (ﺣ) U+FEED (ﻭ)`.

Comment: `arabic_reshaper` converts Arabic Unicode characters into their equivalents in the presentation forms so U+0648 is converted to U+FEED, etc. `bidi.algorithm.get_display` coverts a RTL logically ordered string to a visually ordered string. This reverses the string and as a consequence changes the  order of words. You pass this changed version of the string to the paragraph formatter. What you expect is based on a logically ordered string, but you pass a visually ordered string and that is used to generate your results.

Comment: What is your `paragraph_style`?

Comment: This is one of them I've tested.
    leading_text_style = ParagraphStyle(
    "ordinary_text_style",  # border on
    parent=styles[
        "Normal"
    ],
    ta="left",
    lineSpacing=-10,

    fontName="Arabic",  # previously we named our custom font "Arabic"
    dir="rtl",
)

Comment: Going through some old threads on the reportlab list, it appears that python-bidi and arabic-reshaper will not work. The processing needs to occur on each line. In theory you'd pass plain Unicode, then within internal functions reportlab would use pyfribidi to reformat each line. Initial RTL work was done for Hebrew about 14 years ago. I am trying to ascertain the current status of RTL support, and how to enable it.

Comment: Thank you. What I am doing now is a similar solution with bidi. I am working on a text wrapper, but I have to provide the paragraph width so we have the desired output. Btw, pyfribidi results in the same problem.

Comment: Is there a way to calculate the paragraph with dynamically?

Comment: There is a reportlab setting `rtlSupport`, set this to `1`.  Section 1.8 of the reportlab user guide specifies where you can place override files. On linux and macos I just create a file `~/.reportlab_settings` and enter a line `rtlSupport=1`. Then pass in standard Unicode Arabic text. Don't use python-bidi and arabic-reshaper. Also try to use a simple Naskh font, fonts with sophisticated rendering and typographic features are less likely to work.

Comment: But reportlab RTL rendering is fairly simplistic, so likely to be far from ideal.

Comment: The rendering in the report lab for RTL starts from the bottom of the paragraph. I've created a text wrapper to split and reverse text lines. I need just a little time to work with a test library then I will share my solution.
This is the signature
def text_wrap(_text, _max_width, font_name, font_size):

Comment: This is not the ideal solution but I have to live with it until they fix this issue with RTL texts.

Comment: You need to have libfribidi installed, can be tested with pyfribidi.. Set your `rtlSupport` setting. Add `wordWrap="RTL"` to your `ParagraphStyle` and parse `arabic_text` to `Paragraph()` rather than parsing `bidirectional_text`. Paragraph() will process line by line using fribidi to handle the RTL rendering and swapping in presentational forms on each line.

Comment: I am still phasing the same issue. Check this link. The problem remains the same I think. https://reportlab-users.reportlab.narkive.com/a9RYufEt/hebrew-support-patch

Comment: If you read through that thread, you will see that Moshe implemented initial fribidi support in reportlab. The key is to get fribidi installed. You may need to reinstall reportlab afterwards. If you have fribidi, try the code in my answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Reportlab has partial bidirectional support using Fribidi. It is disabled by default. There is an option `rtlSupport` in `reportlab/rl_settings`. See [user guide](https://www.reportlab.com/docs/reportlab-userguide.pdf#%5B%7B%22num%22%3A228%2C%22gen%22%3A0%7D%2C%7B%22name%22%3A%22Fit%22%7D%5D) section on site configuration. In my installation, I added a file `~/.reportlab_settings` and added the line `rtlSupport=1`.

In `ParagraphStyle()` set `wordWrap="RTL"`.

An example:

```py
from reportlab.platypus import Paragraph
from reportlab.lib.enums import TA_RIGHT
from reportlab.pdfbase import pdfmetrics
from reportlab.pdfbase.ttfonts import TTFont
from reportlab.lib.pagesizes import LETTER
from reportlab.lib.styles import ParagraphStyle, getSampleStyleSheet
from reportlab.platypus.doctemplate import SimpleDocTemplate

pdfmetrics.registerFont(TTFont("Arial Unicode", "Arial Unicode.ttf"))

arabic_text='وحدة1 وحدة2'

doc = SimpleDocTemplate(
    "repro_ar.pdf",
    pagesize=LETTER,
    rightMargin=280,
    leftMargin=280,
    topMargin=72,
    bottomMargin=72,
)
styles = getSampleStyleSheet()
normal_arabic = ParagraphStyle(
    parent=styles["Normal"],
    name="NormalArabic",
    wordWrap="RTL",
    alignment=TA_RIGHT,
    fontName="Arial Unicode",
    fontSize=14,
    leading=16
)

flowables = [Paragraph(arabic_text, normal_arabic)]
doc.build(flowables)
```

This gives me:

[image]

Comment: Work as you said. Thank you.

Comment: Sorry to remove that resolves it. I have a bug with this. Wrapping a long string produces an indentation.

Comment: f"اللقب والاسم: اللقب والاسم: اللقب والاسم: "
                            f"<br />"
                            f" اللقب والاسم: "
                            f"<br />"

you could try this and watch the difference.

Comment: Resolved. I've to use arabic resharper too. supplier_string_format = format_supplier_string(supplier)
                    reshaped_text = arabic_reshaper.reshape(supplier_string_format)
                    return Paragraph(reshaped_text, ___leading_text_style)

Comment: @Mounir, In theory fribidi also does the same reshaping, but I suspect that the line lengths/layout calculations are done before the text is passed to fribidi and throwing the lines off. I tried different margins, different lines of numbers, the results were not consistent. As you indicate arabic_resharper applied before creating the Paragraph object solved the problem. As a rule I tend to use `from arabic_reshaper import ArabicReshaper` so i can pass configuration information including language to the reshaper.

Comment: I've created a class to fix this issue.
`class ArabicParagraph(Paragraph):
    def __init__(self, arabic_text: str, paragraph_style: ParagraphStyle):
        reshaped_text = arabic_reshaper.reshape(arabic_text)
        super().__init__(reshaped_text, paragraph_style)`